# Filling a path with a color and a pattern simultaneously

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, pattern

I would like a rectangle with the following style:

[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=gray,pattern=bricks] (0,0) rectangle (5,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use the preceding code but the output is merely: [image]

Why does this method fail? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pattern` is also a kind of filling. So it overwrites the `fill` option. But you can use `preaction` to fill the path with the color before it is filled by the pattern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
  [pattern=bricks]
  [preaction={fill=gray}]
  (0,0) rectangle (5,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to save your path in a macro, let's say `\mypath` and then apply `\fill` and `\pattern` to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\mypath{(0,0) rectangle (5,-1)}
    \fill [gray] \mypath;
    \pattern [pattern=bricks] \mypath;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]